# Powershell Select-String parse email from .rtf to .csv

Tags: powershell

Parse .rtf file, output email addresses in .csv file?

I have an .rtf file containing a bunch of email addresses, I need this parsed so that I can compare a .csv file to active users in Active Directory.

Basically I want what is to the left of "@my.domain.com"

```
$finds = Select-String -Path "path\to\my.rtf" -Pattern "@my.domain.com" | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches}
$finds | Select-Object -First 1 | ft *
```

This of course gives me one result so that I don't have alot of output.
I only manage to get matches or the complete line.

I've tried adding something along the line of

```
$finds = Select-String -Path "path\to\my.rtf" -Pattern "\w.@my.domain.com"
```

This gives me the very two last letters in the addresses.

If I keep adding dots to the "wildcard"

```
-Pattern "\w.....@my.domain.com"
```

I also get a ton of numbers/characters (.rtf formatting) for addresses that contains fewer characters.

How do I do this?

**EDIT:** I will update the question as soon as I've found a solution. As of now I'm trying with regular expressions. 
Example:

```
-Pattern "\w*?@my.domain.com"
```

Comment: Have you looked at RTF parsers?

Comment: @vonPryz Thank you, I am looking into that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})"    
$lines = get-content "path\to\your.rtf"
foreach($line in $lines){    
    ([regex]::MAtch($rtfInput, $mpattern, "IgnoreCase ")).value }
```

Comment: Thanks! As soon as I updated my question I saw your answer. I removed my -Pattern and added yours, this did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. My inital code but with a new search pattern.

```
$finds = Select-String -Path "path\to\my.rtf" -Pattern "[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})" | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches}
$finds | Select-Object -First 10 | ft *
```

Thanks!